# Why Yul doesn't have the else block?

Tags: opcode

The [yul documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/yul.html#if) states:

> No “else” block can be defined.

It seems really weird. Yul has much more complex control flow schemes like loops and switches. Also other EVM languages like Solidity support the `else` blocks and they compile to EVM's jump opcodes just fine.

What's the reason behind this design decision?

Answer (score 0):

`if`s are used mostly for revert conditions, where the `else` is simply the continuation of the program. An `if cond { a } else { b }` pattern can be done via `switch cond case 0: b default: a`.